# Transmitting and receiving ARP data on Windows from user mode programs

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, network-programming, windows-networking

(ARP = Address Resolution Protocol - RFC 826)
Is there a way to send and receive ARP traffic on Windows through user world programs? On Linux, we can just create raw sockets to send ARP traffic, but on Windows, my research suggests that we need to write a driver that can be used to send such traffic. I thought about using WinPcap, but it internally installs a driver which can be used to send/receive such traffic.

My question is: without installing a driver, are there any ways in which Windows will allow transmission/reception of ARP packets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to send an ARP packet is *probably* using [`SendARP`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366358.aspx).

You can, then use [`GetIpNetTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365956.aspx) to retrieve the address from the IP stack's ARP table. To be sure you're getting a current address, you usually want to do [`DeleteIpNetEntry`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365882.aspx) to remove the address, then `SendARP`, then wait a while and `GetIpNetTable` (if necessary repeating a few times, until you get one with an entry for the desired address).

Alternatively, for Vista or newer, you can use [`ResolveIpNetEntry2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa814455.aspx) to retrieve the data a bit more directly. This automatically flushes the current entry (if any) for the address, sends an ARP packet, and returns a current result (which is also used to update the stacks's ARP table, if I'm not mistaken).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Are there any ways in which we could control the send/receive of the ARP packets ourselves? I would like to piggyback some information in those packets too. I don't think SendARP allows me to do that.

Comment: @Specksynder: Windows does support raw sockets, but I've tried to use them to do this. I don't see an obvious reason it shouldn't work, but I hesitate to say it will without testing.